# intercept native Android library (cf. *.so / Android NDK)

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-6.0-marshmallow, interception

I'm trying to develop an Cydia Substrate module to intercept a native function of a JNI library. Unfortunately it turned out that CS does not support newer Android versions like Marshmallow, while the Xposed framework does not suppport native code in general.

Are there any solutions for newer Android versions to intercept native libraries (*.so)?

Comment: Did you ever find out an alternative?